# Ruby, fast array manipulation when rendering to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have some big arrays that need to be output to my views as JavaScript arrays, I'm sure this is a pretty typical challange, but say I have the following ruby object:

```
[
  {"timestamp"=>2011-09-07 20:45:00 UTC, "count"=>425.0}, 
  {"timestamp"=>2011-09-07 21:00:00 UTC, "count"=>4552.0}, 
  {"timestamp"=>2011-09-07 21:15:00 UTC, "count"=>4510.0}
]
```

but I need to transform it and render it to my views in my JS like so:

```
[
  [Date.UTC(2011,09,07,20,45,00),425.0],
  [Date.UTC(2011,09,07,21,00,00),4552.0],
  [Date.UTC(2011,09,07,21,15,00),4510.0]
];
```

What is the fastest way to do this? Is there already like a builder I can use or something? My biggest concern for something like this is the time it'll take to build the html because the arrays are sometimes pretty big.

Comment: Why do you need to transform it? Looks like the data is already there..

Comment: I guess I don't mean transform, but like how do I output it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're faced with transforming one array into another, you might want to just use `map` and do it that way:

```
require 'time' # Required for Time.parse, unnecessary otherwise

input = [
  {"timestamp"=>Time.parse('2011-09-07 20:45:00 UTC'), "count"=>425.0}, 
  {"timestamp"=>Time.parse('2011-09-07 21:00:00 UTC'), "count"=>4552.0}, 
  {"timestamp"=>Time.parse('2011-09-07 21:15:00 UTC'), "count"=>4510.0}
]

result = input.map do |v|
  "[Date.UTC(%s), %.1f]" % [ v['timestamp'].strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S'), v['count'] ]
end

puts "[\n  " + result.join(",\n  ") + "\n]"
```

The Enumerable module is full of useful utility methods of this variety.

Comment: This works really really well! Thanks soo much! The issue I'm having is that the month is ahead by one, like 09, is actually october for some reason, so the out put ends out being `Date.UTC(2011,08,13,23,45,00)`, any thoughts!

Comment: Given that the output of `Date.UTC` is defined to be the number of miliseconds since epoch, you might just want to put in `v['timestamp'].to_i*1000` instead of going through all of the messy conversion steps. Otherwise you will have to build up your call by breaking out each of the parts: `v['timestamp'].year`, etc. in order to get the 0-11 formatted month, not 1-12 as is the default.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the choice, you'll have to go through your array to collect the data. But, from what I can see here, it's only a matter of collecting the values of hashes in you array.

```
array.map(&:values)
```

I don't really understand your concern here... Did I miss something?